# "Multiple annotations found at this line: - The markup in the document following the root element must be well- formed

Tags: android, markup

Hi im just started programming and i just get this error message 
"Multiple annotations found at this line:
- The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
     formed."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/jcea"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're closing the LinearLayout twice.  Remove `/>` or `</LinearLayout>` - and a basic XML tutorial will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the LinearLayout element twice.  Remove one of the closing tags, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/jcea"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `/>` with a `>`, or remove the `/`.

In xml, `/>` is another way of closing a tag if it does not have any data associated with it. For example, the following two statements are both valid and identical:

`<tag></tag>`

and

`<tag/>`

That being said, you should change your code snippet to either:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/jcea">
</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/jcea"/>
```